# Overlay text on hover

Tags: html, css, overlay, mousehover

What I want: When the circular image is hovered, a grey overlay should cover the image with a hyperlinked text "Edit" on center of it.

```css
.edit {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    a {
      display: inline-block;
    }
}

.profile-userpic {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  a img {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  &:hover .edit {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-userpic">
   <a href=""><img src=" http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" title=""></a>
   <div class="edit"> <a href="">Edit</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working (once it's compiled of course).

**Edit**: 
if you want your .profile-userpic to be independant and be able to place it anywhere you want (like in your screenshot), you have to change your code a bit.
Instead of setting the height and with on the children elements (the `img` and your edit div), set it on the parent container.

```css
.edit {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.edit a {
  color: white;
}

.profile-userpic {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.profile-userpic a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.profile-userpic:hover .edit {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-userpic">
   <a href=""><img src=" http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" title=""></a>
   <div class="edit"> <a href="">Edit</a></div>
</div>
```

In bonus, here's a fiddle with a nice fadeIn/fadeOut effect in css : https://jsfiddle.net/u999xc85/1/

Comment: when I run this code, the hover overlay is not in the center, when I hover the image it shows me overlay at left side. .

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
now with transition & opacity effect.

```css
    .edit {
        opacity:0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      transition:all 600ms linear 0s;
      border-radius:50%;
    }
    .edit a {
      color: white;
      transition:all 600ms linear 0s;
    }

    .profile-userpic {
      position: relative;
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition:all 600ms linear 0s;
    }
    .profile-userpic a img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transition:all 600ms linear 0s;
    }
    .profile-userpic:hover .edit {
      opacity:1;
      transition:all 600ms linear 0s;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="profile-userpic">
       <a href=""><img src=" http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive" alt="" title=""></a>
       <div class="edit"> <a href="">Edit</a></div>
    </div>
```